# How to attach a jquery plugin to future Elements?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a div element and I am assigning a jquery plugin to it.
The plugin works on that element.

Now I want to clone and appendTo the element. The cloning and append works too but the plugin is not working for the cloned object.

Any idea how to make future (cloned) elements work with that plugin?

```
$("#something").somePlugin();
obj = $("#something").clone();
obj.insertAfter("#blah");
//plugin is not working on "obj"
```

BTW: the plugin I am working with is [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: you are using id attributes so it will work only for one.

Comment: I am sorry, I am using a class: $(".something").somePlugin();

Comment: `$("#something").clone().somePlugin();`?

Comment: if it is select2 just re-initialize the method on the new cloned element obj.insertAfter().select2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clone function has a parameter with which you can determine whether you want to also clone 
all the events and data of the given object.

```
obj = $("#something").clone(true);
```